# Same file system but different hardware abstraction confusion

Tags: linux, drivers, filesystems, fat32, block-device

I still don't fully grasp how file systems work deep down.

For example, I have both a hard disk drive and a Flash USB stick connected to my Linux or Windows computer.

I'm presented with options of different file system types to format with, for example FAT32 and NTFS.

I format both devices for FAT32 (Just picking any for an example).

On my computer, I guess that there is a driver / interface for the FAT32 filesystem type.

However, at a lower level, writing and reading bytes to and from both devices will work differently right?

Therefore, in between the filesystem driver and hardware, there should be another hardware-specific driver? If so, Is this control logic on the device itself or on my Windows or Linux computer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The operation will not be as different as you think. for instance the USB specification allows different vendors to write different code that does more or less the same thing, because the end result is a standards compliant USB stack that functions. FAT32 provides a similar specification describing the resulting state, and the kernel needs to be able to conform to that result, even if it got there a little differently than another implementation did. Most common hardware uses generic drivers that will work for all or most hardware of that type. Video cards are sophisticated but usb is simple.

Comment: You need to be aware of layers, e.g. like a protocol stack, in the operating system.  *"Therefore, in between the filesystem driver and hardware, there should be another hardware-specific driver?"* -- Yes.  A device driver in general simply provides access to a peripheral, ignores the data content, and transfers data in chunks supported by the device, e.g. sector or LBA, Ethernet frame, or individual bytes.  Even device drivers can be layered, e.g. SATA over USB.